# Prisma modeling a table with a 1-m self-relationship gives opposite relation error

Tags: prisma

Started using Prisma relatively recent and I'm modeling a `comment` table.
So far it works, meaning a User can post a comment but I am having some issues with replies to comments (or child comments), as a comment can have many child comments, etc.

My current table looks like this:

```
model Comment {
    id              String   @id @default(cuid())
    content         String   @db.VarChar(255)
    User            User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId          String?
    createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
    parentComment   Comment? @relation("RepliesTo", fields: [parentCommentId], references: [id])
    parentCommentId String?

    @@index([userId])
    @@map(name: "post")
}
```

I've added the two lines `parentCommentId` and `parentComment` as a self 1-m relation but VSC keeps giving me this error:

**Error validating field `parentPost` in model `Post`: The relation field `parentPost` on model `Post` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `Post`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually.**

If i let VSC auto complete the code, it just gives me a mess of additional self-referencing rows which make no sense and won't work, and I have no idea how to fix this.

I've read the prisma docs [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations) about self relations, but it didn't help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need 3 fields to make a 1-m relationship.
You are missing a field that will store the list of comments (children) of that parent.

```
model Comment {
    id              String   @id @default(cuid())
    content         String   @db.VarChar(255)
    User            User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId          String?
    createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
    parentComment   Comment? @relation("RepliesTo", fields: [parentCommentId], references: [id])
    parentCommentId String?
    subComments Comment[] @relation("RepliesTo") //This part is missing

    @@index([userId])
    @@map(name: "post")
}
```

[Prisma 1-m](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#one-to-many-self-relations)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just tested and it is working. Thanks for the reply. I'll create a separate comment to explain the reason in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The above comment is 100% correct, tested the code and it's working.

Just wanted to provide more details, maybe it'll be of some help to anyone reading.

After looking at the docs (that I provided in my OP) in greater details i found the answer in plain sight: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#one-to-many-self-relations

We've established a bidirectional relationship by specifying @relation("RepliesTo") for both `parentComment` and `subComments`. This allows you to access all replies to a comment and the parent comment of a reply.